# Datalab kernel crashes because of data set size. Is load balancing an option?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datalab

I am currently running the virtual machine with the highest memory,n1-highmem-32 (32 vCPUs, 208 GB memory).

My data set is around 90 gigs, but has the potential to grow in the future.

The data is in stored in many zipped csv files. I am loading the data into a sparse matrix in order to preform some dimensionality reduction and clustering.

Comment: Can you add more details? What kind of crash do you get? Is there a stack trace? Steps would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The Datalab kernel runs on a single machine.  Since you are already running on a 208GB RAM machine, you may have to switch to a distributed system to analyze the data.

If the operations you are doing on the data can be expressed as SQL, I'd suggest loading the data into BigQuery, which Datalab has a lot of support for.  Otherwise you may want to convert your processing pipeline to use Dataflow (which has a Python SDK).  Depending on the complexity of your operations, either of these may be difficult, though.

Comment: Would it be the case that crashes that occur with lower memory compute instance (in my case a 60GB with 16 cpus).  I have a fairly large dataset I'm trying to run a classifier on.  Kernel crashes. should I scale up the compute instance size?